# django: check for modeladmin for a given model

Tags: django, django-admin

How does one check to see if a modeladmin exists for a given model?

modeladmins are created by registering a model with the admin.site object.  how can one check the site object to see which models have been registered, and with which admin_class?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interesting question, which provoked me to do a little digging.

Once the admin classes have been registered, they are stored in an attribute of the `site` object called - not surprisingly - `_registry`. This is a dictionary of model classes to modeladmin classes - note both the keys and values are *classes*, not names.

So if you have an admin.py like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2')

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

then once that has actually been imported - usually by the `admin.autodiscover()` line in urls.py - `admin.site._registry` will contain something like this:

```
{<class 'myapp.models.MyModel'>: 
    <django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin object at 0x10210ba50>}
```

and you would get the ModelAdmin object for `MyModel` by using the model itself as the key:

```
>>> admin.site._registry[MyModel]
<django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin object at 0x10210ba50>
```

Comment: hmmm... this was also my first attempt, but there was nothing in _registry.. probably because I checked from manage.py shell, and autodiscover hadn't been called.  This might be it!

Comment: thanks! works perfectly in **Django 1.4**, but isn't there a method to access directly the ModelAdmin from within the Model? it would be prettier than my method: `admin.site._registry[obj.__class__]` :)

Comment: @caesarsol your model should know nothing about admin because of MVC - Django is not really MVC, but close to it

Comment: @KarolisRyselis you are absolutely right, I don't even remember what I would have used this for... I knew nothing about the SOLID principles in 2013 :)

Answer (score 3):

Django's `django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite` has a method for checking registered Model called `.is_registered(model)`. This method will check on the admin site's `_registry` attribute (just like [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)'s approach)

So, if you have files like these:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model)
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
```

```py
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2')

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

You could make some test like this:

```py
# tests.py

from django.test import TestCase
from .models import MyModel

class TestModelAdmin(TestCase):

    def test_mymodel_registered(self):
        self.assertTrue(admin.site.is_registered(MyModel))
```

> nb: I've checked it on the Django's modules documentation from [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/admin/sites/#AdminSite) to [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/sites/#AdminSite)